# Proving u$_p$ + u$_q$ = u$_r$ + u$_s$ if, and only if p+q = r+s

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

I tried finding explanations on this proof online but I think the level of 'English' makes it almost impossible for me to understand the mathematics they are trying to explain.

When u$_n$ is an arithmetical series, how do you prove that:

$\forall$p,q,r,s $\in$ N$_0$ : u$_p$+u$_q$ = u$_r$+u$_s$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ p+q = r+s

A step in the right direction would be very helpfull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u_n=an+b$, where $a\neq 0$, as $u_n$ is an arithmetic series.

$u_p=ap+b\tag{1}$

$u_q=aq+b\tag{2}$

$u_r=ar+b\tag{3}$

$u_s=as+b\tag{4}$

Using $(1),(2),(3)$ and $(4)$, we have

$$u_p+u_q=u_r+u_s$$

$$\Rightarrow ap+b+aq+b=ar+b+as+b$$

$$\Rightarrow a(p+q)=a(r+s)$$

$$\Rightarrow p+q=r+s \text{, as } a \neq 0$$

Comment: Wow.. I really was looking for a much too difficult answer haha thanks!

Comment: now as a follow-up. 
Arithmatic series can be translated in to something in the form of ax+b.
Is there a formula likewise for geometric series?

Comment: @Michelle_B Yes, it is of the form $g_n=ar^{n-1}$, where $a$ is the first term and $r$ is the common ratio.